# 'Contact' object has no attribute 'first_name'

Tags: python, django

My code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db import connection

class Contact(models.Model):

#Retrieving data from a database
    # #Create the cursor
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    #Write the SQL code
    sql_string = 'SELECT * FROM contacts_contact'
    #Execute the SQL
    cursor.execute(sql_string)

    #Print more than two: for row in cursor.fetchall: print(row[1])
    #Print one record
    print("\033[92m View a sample record: \033[93m" + cursor.fetchone()[1] + "\033[0m")


    def form():
        first_name = models.CharField(
            max_length = 255,
        )
        last_name = models.CharField(
            max_length = 255,
        )
        email = models.EmailField()
        file = models.FileField(upload_to='files/')

    form()

    def __str__(self):
        return ' '.join([
            self.first_name,
            self.last_name,
        ])
```

And my error: 'Contact' object has no attribute 'first_name'

If the code of the "forms" ladies elsewhere, then it is all right.

Please help

Comment: you shouldn't execute commands inside a class definition

Comment: Your code is fundamentally flawed.  There are too many things here to correct.  You should go through the basic django tutorial at the very least before asking for help here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 2):

This entire code is complete nonsense, unfortunately. You need to go back and do the tutorial: nothing you are doing here makes sense. You don't need SQL commands; if you did, you wouldn't do them at the class level; you *do* need to put the field definitions at the class level rather than inside a strangely-named `form` method; you shouldn't call a method immediately after defining it within the class; and so on.

Comment: Okay, could you write me a sample code how you want it?
I realized that nothing I can do. I do not know if only in python, like writing code in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Why should local variables in the function `form` become magically class attributes?

```
from django.db import models
from django.db import connection

class Contact(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(
        max_length = 255,
    )
    last_name = models.CharField(
        max_length = 255,
    )
    email = models.EmailField()
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='files/')

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (
            self.first_name,
            self.last_name,
        )
```

Classes are only for definitions, not for executing code.